# C++ Arduino: adding and getting values from hashmap returns garbage values

Tags: c++, arduino, hashmap

I've got a small program on my Arduino, in which I use the HashMap lib from Wiring framework. 
Anyways, the HashMap is of key type char *, and value type char * as well.
I read some keys and values from a file and I try to add them to the map. I read them as Strings, and then I use the .c_str() method to convert them into char *. 
When I then print the map, I get very weird values, which I think might be garbage from the memory?
Anyone knows how can I fix that, and why that happens? I was thinking it might have to do something with the temporary values in the memory returned by .c_str(), but I'm not sure. Any help? 
Here is the code: (st is just a string and I split it into two, where the : is).

```
    String msgC = st.substring(0, st.indexOf(":") - 1);
    const char* messageCode = msgC.c_str();
    String msg = st.substring(st.indexOf(":") + 1);
    const char* message = msg.c_str();
    hashMap[messageCode] = message;
```

When I print the 'message' and 'messageCode' into the console, they are fine.
Output when I print the hashmap:

Key: rently wiping, hig& Value: B0 D8 0 BE A0 9B 86:Wipers currently wiping, hig&
Key:  Value: ⸮pers currently wiping, high speed.

Key:  Value: ⸮

EDIT:
When I use String types of the hashMap key and values, I get more strange behavior:

```
if (dataFile)   { 
  String st;
 while (dataFile.available() > 0) {
  char s = char(dataFile.read());
  if (s!='\n'){
    st = st+s;
  }
  else{
    String msgC = st.substring(0, st.indexOf(":") - 1);
    String msg = st.substring(st.indexOf(":") + 1);
    Serial.print(msgC + " " + msg);
    hashMap[msgC] = msg;
    st = "";
  }
}
```

Now the first three pairs of msgC and msg are read and stored fine. But the rest get split mid sentence or are not loaded at all. The output from the Serial.print: 
1D0 834 B0 D8 0 A0 A0 9B 8 Wipers are off. 
1D0 834 B0 D8 0 A8 A0 9B 8 Wipers on, single wipe. 
1D0 834 B0 D8 0 A1 A0 9B 8 Wipers are on, not wiping. 
(Up until here it's ok)

currently wiping, low speed.
 currently wiping, low speed.
tly wiping, medium speed.
 tly wiping, medium speed.
urrently wiping, high speed.
 urrently wiping, high speed.

Weird stuff. And this did not happen when I used char * in the HashMap, and I did not change anything else in the code. How come that changing the type of HashMap keys and values could affect this reading from a file?

Comment: `const char *` is a pointer, not a string. `messageCode` points to data of `msgC`. If `msgC` disappears `messageCode` points to garbage. Either make sure the things pointed to by your `const char *`s stay valid until you are done with the map or use a map of strings instead.

Comment: @nwp so how to I make sure that they stay valid? How do I make some kind of a copy?

Comment: Instead of `hashmap<const char *, const char *>` you use `hashmap<String, String>`. That way the map owns the strings and they will not become invalid until after the map is gone.

Comment: When I use String, I get quite strange behavior also, but I'm not sure if it's due to the memory or not, since Arduino has only 256kb of memory.

Comment: Maybe make a new question with the `String` version. But instead of "I get strange behavior" try to make a [mcve] so people have a chance to understand, reproduce and fix the issue.

Comment: I edited this current question with the extra case. Can you take a look ?

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code. I have no clue what is wrong with your file reading because I can neither see the file nor the function to read it. You may have some undefined behavior somewhere which can produce all kinds of crazy effects.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding only *pointer* to data into hashmap:

```
 String msg = st.substring(st.indexOf(":") + 1);
 const char* message = msg.c_str();
 hashMap[messageCode] = message;
```

Once `msg` is destroyed, the memory pointed by `message` becomes free for usage, so it is **Undefined Behavior**.

Your hash map should actually contains `String` values instead of `char*`.

Comment: I've edited the current question to what happens when I use Strings. Can you take a look ?